# Error: Illegal Character 2

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I'm not too exposed to Javascript (only for this mini piece of work) however I'm trying to help a friend add a dynamic field to show the username and date when an Acrobat form was updated.

So far I have the following:

```
Event.value = (new Date()).toString();
AFDate_FormatEX("h:MM,mmm dd, yyy");
Event.value = "By" + ((!identity.name||identity.loginName !=(event.source.source||this)Collab.user)?
(even.source.source||this).collab.user:identity.name) + "at" + event.value;
```

Unfortunately this is throwing an error saying 'Illegal Character 2' (screenshot below). I tried googling this error to no avail - what am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: It also appears that your JavaScript is using “slanty quotes” instead of "straight quotes".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
(event.source.source||this)Collab.user
```

As far as I am aware, this is illegal. Based on what is further down, there should be a "." between ")" and "Collab":

```
(event.source.source||this).Collab.user
```